# JQuery code to check that div does not have class not working

Tags: jquery, css

I have some JQuery code that enables Bootstrap navbar dropdown menus to automatically expand on mouseover. I have one dropdown menu that I am using as a language menu, which just has a flag icon. For this div I assign a custom CSS class which hides the carot in the dropdown menu.

I am trying to get JQuery to check if the div is assigned a class 'carot-off' and ignore it if that is the case, but what I have is not working.

This is my code so far:

```css
.caret-off::before {
    display: none;
}
.caret-off::after {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown link
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle caret-off" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown link
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
<script>
const $dropdown = $(".dropdown");
const $dropdownToggle = $(".dropdown-toggle");
const $dropdownMenu = $(".dropdown-menu");
const showClass = "show";
 
$(window).on("load resize", function() {
  if (this.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)").matches) {
    $dropdown.hover(
      function() {
        const $this = $(this);
        $this.addClass(showClass);
        if (!$(this).hasClass("caret-off")) {
        $this.find($dropdownToggle).attr("aria-expanded", "true");
        $this.find($dropdownMenu).addClass(showClass);
        }
      },
      function() {
        const $this = $(this);
        $this.removeClass(showClass);
        if (!$(this).hasClass("caret-off")) {
        $this.find($dropdownToggle).attr("aria-expanded", "false");
        $this.find($dropdownMenu).removeClass(showClass);
        }
      }
    );
  } else {
    $dropdown.off("mouseenter mouseleave");
  }
});
</script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Using `if (!$(this).hasClass("caret-off"))` seems like it should be correct, but it has no effect at all. Am I doing something wrong? Is my approach incorrect?

Comment: I don't see you ever adding or removing the class "caret-off". Only the class "show".

Comment: @John that's right, I don't want to add or remove the class 'caret-off', I want to avoid adding or removing the class 'show' to a div that has the class 'caret-off'.

Comment: can you create a JSFiddle for your question, seeing which we can easily help you out?

Comment: @PrasadWargad All code should be included in the question itself, not in external links. @Jake, Prasad is right in saying that seeing the problem in action will help us to help you... the question can be edited to include a runnable snippet using the `[<>]` button in the edit.

Comment: Are you sure that your event is firing? When I ran the snippet, the load and resize events didn't fire. Also, your `<li>` has the dropdown class, but it's the `<a>` that has the caret-off class.

Comment: @mankowitz I had some issues trying to remove the responsiveness from the snippet. I don't think it fires in the responsive view, but on my local machine in a test file in full desktop mode it does. At least, when I mouse over dropdown menus they expand as they should automatically as per the code. I added caret-off to the `<a>` because it wasn't displaying, and it turns out it is actually the `dropdown-toggle` class that adds the caret.

Comment: @JakeRankin: navbar toggle was not working because of incorrect id passed to it, just corrected it. Now navbar toggle option will work and you will be able to see the menus. Your code is working fine, if you removed the resize condition, menus are getting seen on hovering.

Comment: @PrasadWargad I'm unsure how to get it ti display in the snippet correctly, as I think the responsiveness is affecting things. If I copy the code from the snippet into a new HTML file, and add the CSS to with `<style>` tags and run it locally, it works as it should and demonstrates the problem. Which is that there are two dropdown menus, one not showing a caret due to the caret-off class, and I want the jQuery code to ignore this div, but it is not. I don't expect the jQuery code to execute when the menu is condensed as in the responsive view in the snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`caret-off` class is given to HTML anchor tags having class as `dropdown-toggle`.
And the code was checking the condition `$(this).hasClass("caret-off")`, this condition was getting applied to HTML elements `$(".dropdown")`.

So corrected the condition to `$(this).find($dropdownToggle).hasClass("caret-off")`, which checks whether gonna be toggle dropdown element have `caret-off` class or not. If that element don't have a `caret-off` class then only submenus will get expanded.

To demonstrate the working answer, I have commented the condition to check responsiveness. Which you can add it.

```js
const $dropdown = $(".dropdown");
const $dropdownToggle = $(".dropdown-toggle");
const $dropdownMenu = $(".dropdown-menu");
const showClass = "show";
 
$(window).on("load resize", function() {
  //if (this.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)").matches) {
    $dropdown.hover(
      function() {
        const $this = $(this);
        $this.addClass(showClass);
        if (!$(this).find($dropdownToggle).hasClass("caret-off")) {
        $this.find($dropdownToggle).attr("aria-expanded", "true");
        $this.find($dropdownMenu).addClass(showClass);
        }
      },
      function() {
        const $this = $(this);
        $this.removeClass(showClass);
        if (!$(this).find($dropdownToggle).hasClass("caret-off")) {
        $this.find($dropdownToggle).attr("aria-expanded", "false");
        $this.find($dropdownMenu).removeClass(showClass);
        }
      }
    );
  //} else {
  //  $dropdown.off("mouseenter mouseleave");
  //}
});
```

```css
.caret-off::before {
    display: none!important;
}
.caret-off::after {
    display: none!important;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle caret-off" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```