# CSS class to remove caret in Bootstrap dropdown menu being ignored

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following CSS classes to remove the caret from a Bootstrap dropdown menu:

```
.caret-off::before {
    display: none;
}
.caret-off::after {
    display: none;
}
```

For a normal dropdown menu, adding the 'caret-off' class to a dropdown menu item works absolutely perfectly. The dropdown functions normally and the caret is not displayed.

However, when I attempt to add this class in conjunction with one of the directional dropdown variants, it does not work at all. In my case, I am trying to use it in conjunction with a dropdown-left menu. The dropdown works as it should, but my 'caret-off' class has no effect.

Why?

Example:

```css
.caret-off::before {
    display: none;
}
.caret-off::after {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle caret-off" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown dropdown-left">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle caret-off" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this related to your [other question about adding your `.caret-off` class using jQuery]?(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62964318/jquery-code-to-check-that-div-does-not-have-class-not-working)

Comment: @FluffyKitten They are separate issues. This issue has nothing to do with jQuery and is specific to Bootstrap. The other issue is specific to jQuery and has nothing to do with Bootstrap specifically.

Comment: Then please include your relevant code in a [minimal, **reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see the problem and be able to help. Showing us 2 CSS rules is not enough to tell us what might be going wrong.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I'm familiar with the posting rules here at SO. I'm specifically referencing specific classes that come with Bootstrap in my question, and I didn't think adding in boilerplate code would be useful, at least I think the messiness outweighs the utility, but I'll add something in.

Comment: We don't need to see the boilerplate bootstrap CSS (we know *that* works), we need to see the code that you are having the problem with so that we can see where the issue might be happening... as I said, just showing us 2 CSS rules doesn't tell us *anything* about what is going wrong, and as the bootstrap code obviously works then the problem is obviously somewhere else...

Comment: @FluffyKitten The issue applies to boilerplate bootstrap. The code I am working in was taken from the example in their documentation. Literally all I did was add the caret-off class. If I had more specific code I would have included it. You're right just showing 2 CSS rules doesn't show what is going wrong, which is why I provided an explanation in addition. Anyway, I added a snippet using the example from the tutorial using the CSS rules already in the question.

Comment: Except that you didn't explain where you got that example code or which version of Bootstrap you are using. But now that you have actually gives us an MRE (well an RE... not so sure about the minimal part) so that we can actually see the problem in action, my guess is that you are using code from an example for one version of bootstrap (most likely 3) in code that is using Bootstrap 4.5.

Comment: "*I am not mixing versions of bootstrap*"... that's *not* what I said. I said the *example* you used  might have been for Bootstrap 3. And whether *you* think the CSS class was sufficient or not really doesn't matter... what matters is whether *the people trying to help you* think it's enough or whether we want more information to be able to help *you*! If *we* don't think we have enough, we *can't* help. Anyway, once you gave us the MRE I was able to help, so glad you got sorted.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I deleted the comment before you replied. Not interested in petty squabbling. Agree to disagree and appreciate your answer below.

Comment: "*Not interested in petty squabbling.*" Neither am I, I'm just pointing out what you need to do to get the help you need, so now you know for future questions. As I said, glad you got it sorted.

Comment: @FluffyKitten - Yet you continue the conversation? The Bootstrap example code wasn't necessary in this case, and maybe others with more familiarity with Bootstrap would agree. I'm glad it helped you to answer the question and in turn help me. I'm not new to the site, and I added the information that I deemed sufficient without complicating the question with excessive code, which IMO adding example code directly from the documentation does. Can we end this now please? I thought it would have ended at agree to disagree but apparently not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dropdown-toggle` class adds the caret, so you need to use a more specific CSS rule to target it than just `caret-off`. This following CSS rule will work:

```
.dropdown-toggle.caret-off::after {
    display: none;
}
```

You can see here that the caret no longer appears on the `dropdown-toggle` class using this more specific CSS:

```css
.dropdown-toggle.caret-off::after {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle caret-off" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown dropdown-left">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle caret-off" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked, thank you for an answer and the explanation as to why the CSS had to be more specific.